# jQuery AJAX Post not posting data weird bug

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, post

I have been trying to figure this bug out for over 2 hours:

I am trying to send POST data to a php page via ajax using codeignitor when a form is submitted:

```
$("#advertise-form").submit(function( event ) {

 //random stuff above
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({   
url: '<?php echo base_url();?>advertise/get_advertisement',   
    type: "POST",
    data : $(this).serialize(),
     success: function(){
     alert("IT WORKED");
     },
 error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
     console.log(error);
     }
});   
return false;
});
```

now this is the weird part, if I change the url to

```
'<?php echo base_url();?>register/add_account'
```

it works...I have no idea why

chrome console logs

```
[X]POST http://**DOMAIN**/advertise/get_advertisement  
  send
  b.extend.ajax
  (anonymous function)
  b.event.dispatch
  v.handle
```

EDIT:: I am 100% certain the page exists

EDIT:
Error messages are:

```
textStatus -> error
xhr -> [object Object]
error was blank
```

Comment: What error or unexpected response are you getting? We need more info than that it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, a error in the console is being displayed and the alert is not appearing

Comment: What I mean is, what is in `xhr` and `textStatus`? Those will be informative.

Comment: Replace that console.log(error) with alert(textStatus);

Comment: Telling us "error in the console is being displayed" and not telling us what the error message is is pretty pointless, don't you think?

Comment: textStatus: error, xhr: Object object, error was blank

Comment: try to replace $(this) with $("#advertise-form"), i'm not sure if this is the form this

Comment: is this url '<?php echo base_url();?>advertise/get_advertisement'
require authentication? if yes try to make the function available for not logged in user, to check if the problem related to auth or not

Comment: The page did require authentication, however I removed everything and still the same problem